# While loop with 2 conditions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want my while loop to match 2 conditions in order to break the loop - `res` has to NOT be undefined, which is the case only when status code is 200, and `obj.owner` has to be equal to some value i set. It takes a couple of seconds for the owner on that page to update, so i need the while loop to run until the owner updates.

Here's the request function

```
const getOwner = () => {
  const opts = {
    url: 'https://example.com',
    json: true,
    simple: false,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }

  return request(opts)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {

        const obj = {
          owner: res.body.owner
        }

        return obj

      } else {
        console.error(`Error: ${res.statusCode}`)
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(`Panic: ` + e.message)
    })
}
```

And here's the while loop

```
let owner = await getOwner()
while (!owner && owner.owner != 'some value') {
  owner = await getOwner()
}

console.log('Loop broken')
```

When I `console.log(!owner, (owner.owner != 'some value'))` after the first function call, before trying to enter into the loop, it returns `false` for the first condition, and `true` for the second.

When status code is other than 200, it doesnt return the object, so i need those 2 conditions together, as otherwise it crashes the program due to `owner` being undefined.

Now, when i execute this, it always skips the loop no matter what, im really lost at this point.

Comment: have you put a console log inside the loop to make sure it is skipping the loop? Right now this will run if 1) there is no owner and 2) `owner.owner` is anything other than '`some value'`. Could owner.owner always be `some value`?

Comment: @about14sheep yes i have done that, and it is definitely skipping the loop fully. I've also logged the `!owner` and ``owner.owner != 'some value'`` values, first one is false and second is true, and the loop is still being skipped..

Comment: if the first one comes up false it will skip it. the loop will only run if both are true. Have you made sure owner is not a promise?

Comment: @about14sheep so how can i make sure that owner is not undefined and is equal to the value?

Comment: so you want to make sure it is not undefined AND equal to `some value`? change `!=` to `===`. I would console log owner immediately after you get it, right before the while loop line, and see what it is. Because if you are saying it is returns false for `!owner` than it is a falsy value like undefined

Comment: No as in, i want it to leave the loop only when owner is not undefined and owner.owner is equal to ``some value``

Comment: From what you have said in the comments, I think owner is returning undefined. try console logging `res` in your fetch call and see what the status code is

Comment: Why are you calling the same function over and over and expecting a different result?

Comment: And since `getOwner()` accepts no arguments and doesn't mutate any state, it shouldn't be returning a different value every time you call it.

Comment: Also, the `getOwner()` function resolves to `undefined` if you get a non-200 status.  So, if that API every returns non-200, you will infinite loop hammering that API as fast as your CPU possibly can.  One should NEVER design code that does that.  If you want to retry upon error, look for specific errors that a retry is appropriate on, wait a short delay before retrying and retry a maximum number of times (like 5).  Would you like a bunch of clients to have this kind of code operating against your server?  No, you would not.  This kind of code leads to avalanche failures.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's a bad idea to loop through a resource until you get the intended result you are seeking.

If you have control over the resource that you are calling, change it to return the result according to your expectation.

If you do not have control over the resource, in my opinion, the resource should not be return different results on different calls. If you get a different response on each call, then the resource is not idempotent. It's a bad design.
Imagine, you would be looping n times, with that you may or may not get the results you are looking for.

I would suggest looking into implementation and fixing the root of the problem, rather than work around.

Comment: Excellent points.  This appears to be a bad looping design and the design should be fixed rather than try to put some lipstick on this bad implementation.  Why would a function called rapidly in a loop ever return a different value?  There's occasionally a reason for retry upon error, but even then not in a rapid fire loop like this and never in a forever `while` loop when there isn't even an error communicated back.

Answer (score 0):

`getOwner` returns a `Promise`. You will need to `await` for it. And I don't think you really need the `while` loop:

```js
let owner = await getOwner();
if(owner && owner.owner != 'some value') {
  /*do stuff with owner*/
}
console.log(owner);
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include that in my question, as i had to write a new function to not share anything sensitive from the original one. But yes i am awaiting it already and the result is still the same.